# Commerce JS API rejecting my test transaction

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce

I'm having a tricky problem. I've created this ecommerce platform with react and I'm using the commerce JS API. I connected my sandbox stripe API key with the sandbox commerce JS key so I could do a test transaction, but each time I get an error and the transaction doesn't go through, leaving my cart quantity unchanged.

In console I get the following error from the commerce JS API:

[image]

According to the commerce JS developer setting logs this is the request I'm sending:

```
{
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": "item_7RyWOwmK5nEa2V",
      "product_id": "prod_LvJjoPJGale0nO",
      "name": "Ferrari",
      "product_name": "Ferrari",
      "media": {
        "type": "image",
        "source": "https://cdn.chec.io/merchants/28537/assets/o0wPb0EDWAlJnEV1|1.jpg"
      },
      "sku": null,
      "permalink": "kKwz9a",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": {
        "raw": 1.5,
        "formatted": "1.50",
        "formatted_with_symbol": "£1.50",
        "formatted_with_code": "1.50 GBP"
      },
      "line_total": {
        "raw": 1.5,
        "formatted": "1.50",
        "formatted_with_symbol": "£1.50",
        "formatted_with_code": "1.50 GBP"
      },
      "is_valid": true,
      "product_meta": [],
      "tax": {
        "is_taxable": false,
        "taxable_amount": null,
        "amount": null,
        "breakdown": null
      },
      "selected_options": [],
      "variant": []
    }
  ],
  "customer": [],
  "shipping": {
    "name": "Primary",
    "county_state": "WSM",
    "country": "GB"
  },
  "fulfillment": {
    "shipping_method": "ship_RqEv5xvDqwZz4j"
  },
  "payment": {
    "gateway": "stripe",
    "stripe": {
      "payment_method_id": "pm_1J1FitHjVwDyRBqGNRnw8Ryt"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand how the email field, shipping address and shipping town/city are missing, as this is what my submission form looks like:

[image]

I filled in everything accurately.

Here is my AddressForm component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  Button,
  Grid,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { commerce } from "../../lib/commerce";
import FormInput from "./CustomTextField";

const AddressForm = ({ checkoutToken, next }) => {
  const [shippingCountries, setShippingCountries] = useState([]);
  const [shippingCountry, setShippingCountry] = useState("");
  const [shippingSubdivisions, setShippingSubdivisions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingSubdivision, setShippingSubdivision] = useState("");
  const [shippingOptions, setShippingOptions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingOption, setShippingOption] = useState("");
  const methods = useForm();

  const fetchShippingCountries = async (checkoutTokenId) => {
    const { countries } = await commerce.services.localeListShippingCountries(
      checkoutTokenId
    );

    setShippingCountries(countries);
    setShippingCountry(Object.keys(countries)[0]);
  };

  const fetchSubdivisions = async (countryCode) => {
    const { subdivisions } = await commerce.services.localeListSubdivisions(
      countryCode
    );

    setShippingSubdivisions(subdivisions);
    setShippingSubdivision(Object.keys(subdivisions)[0]);
  };

  const fetchShippingOptions = async (
    checkoutTokenId,
    country,
    region = null
  ) => {
    const options = await commerce.checkout.getShippingOptions(
      checkoutTokenId,
      { country, region }
    );

    setShippingOptions(options);
    setShippingOption(options[0].id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingCountry) fetchSubdivisions(shippingCountry);
  }, [shippingCountry]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingSubdivision)
      fetchShippingOptions(
        checkoutToken.id,
        shippingCountry,
        shippingSubdivision
      );
  }, [shippingSubdivision]);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Shipping address
      </Typography>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) =>
            next({
              ...data,
              shippingCountry,
              shippingSubdivision,
              shippingOption,
            })
          )}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <FormInput required name="firstName" label="First name" />{" "}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              {" "}
              <FormInput required name="lastName" label="Last name" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              {" "}
              <FormInput required name="address1" label="Address line 1" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              {" "}
              <FormInput required name="email" label="Email" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              {" "}
              <FormInput required name="city" label="City" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              {" "}
              <FormInput required name="zip" label="Zip / Postal code" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Country</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingCountry}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingCountry(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingCountries)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Subdivision</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingSubdivision}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingSubdivision(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingSubdivisions)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Options</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingOption}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingOption(e.target.value)}
              >
                {shippingOptions
                  .map((sO) => ({
                    id: sO.id,
                    label: `${sO.description} - (${sO.price.formatted_with_symbol})`,
                  }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <Button component={Link} variant="outlined" to="/cart">
              Back to Cart
            </Button>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Next
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddressForm;
```

My payment form component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography, Button, Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
  Elements,
  CardElement,
  ElementsConsumer,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

import Review from "./Review";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);

const PaymentForm = ({
  checkoutToken,
  nextStep,
  backStep,
  shippingData,
  onCaptureCheckout,
}) => {
  const handleSubmit = async (event, elements, stripe) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) return;

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: cardElement,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log("[error]", error);
    } else {
      const orderData = {
        line_items: checkoutToken.live.line_items,
        customer: {
          firstname: shippingData.firstName,
          lastname: shippingData.lastName,
          email: shippingData.email,
        },
        shipping: {
          name: "Primary",
          street: shippingData.address1,
          town_city: shippingData.city,
          county_state: shippingData.shippingSubdivision,
          postal_zip_code: shippingData.zip,
          country: shippingData.shippingCountry,
        },
        fulfillment: { shipping_method: shippingData.shippingOption },
        payment: {
          gateway: "stripe",
          stripe: {
            payment_method_id: paymentMethod.id,
          },
        },
      };

      onCaptureCheckout(checkoutToken.id, orderData);

      nextStep();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Review checkoutToken={checkoutToken} />
      <Divider />
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom style={{ margin: "20px 0" }}>
        Payment method
      </Typography>
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <ElementsConsumer>
          {({ elements, stripe }) => (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, elements, stripe)}>
              <CardElement />
              <br /> <br />
              <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={backStep}>
                  Back
                </Button>
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                  disabled={!stripe}
                  color="primary"
                >
                  Pay {checkoutToken.live.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol}
                </Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          )}
        </ElementsConsumer>
      </Elements>
    </>
  );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

And also my APP JS:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Products, Navbar, Cart, Checkout } from "./components";
import { commerce } from "./lib/commerce";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

    setProducts(data);
  };

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
  };

  const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const { cart } = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

    setCart(cart);
  };

  const handleUpdateCartQty = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const { cart } = await commerce.cart.update(productId, { quantity });
    setCart(cart);
  };

  const handleRemoveFromCart = async (productId) => {
    const { cart } = await commerce.cart.remove(productId);
    setCart(cart);
  };

  const handleEmptyCart = async () => {
    const { cart } = await commerce.cart.empty();
    setCart(cart);
  };

  const refreshCart = async () => {
    const newCart = await commerce.cart.refresh();
    console.log(newCart);
    setCart(newCart);
  };

  const handleCaptureCheckout = async (checkoutTokenId, newOrder) => {
    try {
      const incomingOrder = await commerce.checkout.capture(
        checkoutTokenId,
        newOrder
      );

      setOrder(incomingOrder);

      refreshCart();
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage(error.data.error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart
              cart={cart}
              handleUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty}
              handleRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart}
              handleEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/checkout">
            <Checkout
              cart={cart}
              order={order}
              onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout}
              error={errorMessage}
            />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I spoke to some people on the Commerce JS slack and they pointed out that these fields were 'missing' but I don't understand what they mean by that. I've read that others have had this issue too (specifically people following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=377AQ0y6LPA) so I'm not sure if it's a problem with the code or the API.

I'm at a loss here so I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Console log ur shipping data and check if the names of the objects are the same
for example if : shippingData has the email stored in Email instead of email.So Payment Form cannot recognize the information

Comment: Can you please add an example to your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in your FormInput component check that you use render instead of as props and try to spread param of callback inside ex:

```
<Controller control={control}
                name={name}
                render={({field})=>(<TextField 
                        label={label}
                        {...field}
                        required={required}
                        fullWidth
                        value={field.value}
                />)}
    />
```